# ASP.NET Membership provider Tool

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Is there any tool to configure membership providers in Web.config file from within VS2005?

If yes, then How to use that?

ASP.NET config tool only adds a provider but don't let it configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from within VS directly no. However there is a simple tool if you're using IIS.

For an IIS 6 site, Open IIS Admin, expand the Web Sites node, right click on the site you wish to configure and select properties.

In the properties pane, select the ASP.NET tab, and press "Edit Configuration".

Select the Authentication tab, and in the Membership group, select "Manage Providers".

You should then see a list of providers on the left hand side, and a list of default properties and values on the right hand side, with the ability to edit them - however, note that these aren't strongly typed, so you still have to know what the options are for each setting.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a specific tool on the basis that the Provider Model is designed to be extended and modified to suit your specific applications needs.

We have built our own SQL Membership Provider to support all the standard login control and to enable us to configure the Provider using our own forms within the application (ie reading all the configuration values from the database rather than from the web.config.
Its not such a big task to implement a custom membership provider.